# Pose object movement problem

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigging, pose-mode

I have a character created and rigged in T pose. The character is 'naked'. The Armature is the parent to the 'body'.

I'm trying to add some clothing to the character. I created some simple shorts and used the armature as the parent.

I fixed some issues with 'splitting the shorts' by merging the verts and removing the doubles. I then fixed issues where the shorts were 'stretching' as they moved by setting the rotation and scale.

My issue now, is that when I pose the character and try to move its leg - the leg moves 'outside' of the shorts (like it moves faster and goes outside of the mesh). I've tried weight painting and pretty much every solution I could find but nothing seems to be working.

I'm VERY new to modelling, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance~

Comment: You mean the body is a child of the armature? Otherwise that probably doesn't work properly.
You could try to use a shrinkwrap modifier on your shorts, but that's no guarantee. You could also weight paint the vertices completely hidden by the shorts and use a mask modifier to hide them whenever your character is wearing them.